# Cómo obtengo un valor de js en una variable php

Tags: javascript, php, script

tengo un pequeño problema y es que no sé cómo guardar un valor de un js en una variable php, aquí les dejo mi codigo.

Tengo unos input tipo radio

```
<input type="radio" mame="tipo_cuenta" vale="1" id="1-mes" checked="">
<label for="1-mes">1 Mes</label>

<input type="radio" mame="tipo_cuenta" vale="3" id="3-meses" checked="">
<label for="3-meses">3 Meses</label>

<input type="radio" mame="tipo_cuenta" vale="6" id="6-meses" checked="">
<label for="6-meses">6 Meses</label>
```

Y este es mi script

```
<script>
var valor = '';
$("input[mame='tipo_cuenta']" ).on ('change', function () {
valor = $(thi).val ();
alert(valor);
<\script>
```

El código me funciona perfecto pero el resultado me lo da en un **alert** pero yo en vez de que me lo diga en **alert** quiero que me lo guarde en una variable php.

**Porfa el que me pueda ayudar se lo agradecería muchísimo.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me he encontrado en casos así, yo suelo recomendar usar un form de HTML.

El elemento form puede incluir inputs (tus inputs de tipo radio), y tiene una particularidad muy especial: cuando se envía ese formulario, envía la información que tenga vía petición GET o POST. Esto es muy importante, pues tú puedes acceder al GET o al POST en PHP (usando la variable global `$_GET[]`.

Por lo tanto, tendrías algo así:

```
<form method="GET" action="/" >
    <input type="radio" name="tipo_cuenta" value="1" id="1-mes" checked="">
    <label for="1-mes">1 Mes</label>

    <input type="radio" name="tipo_cuenta" value="3" id="3-meses" checked="">
    <label for="3-meses">3 Meses</label>

    <input type="radio" name="tipo_cuenta" value="6" id="6-meses" checked="">
    <label for="6-meses">6 Meses</label>
</form>
```

Es decir, como todos los input de tipo radio tienen el mismo nombre (tipo_cuenta), al enviar el formulario, podrías acceder en PHP a su valor usando esto:

```
$valor = $_GET['tipo_cuenta]
```

Ahora, la pregunta es: ¿cómo enviar el formulario? Pues hay dos formas.

En primer lugar, podrías poner un botón dentro del form. Sí alguien lo pulsa, se enviaría el formulario y ya podrías acceder a esa variable mediante PHP.

Pero veo que lo que buscas es poder enviar esa variable cuando se selecciona una de ellas. Lamentablemente he olvidado cómo se hace eso, así que ojalá alguien responda con la forma de hacerlo (sé que era en el form, usando la propiedad onchange, algo de form.submit).

Ojalá todo esto te haya servido, un saludo.

Comment: Tambien se puede usar jQuery y AJAX para enviar los datos.  Tiene la ventaja que no hay que hacer un todo ida y vuelta del servidor.

Comment: Sí, así es. Lamentablemente, no conozco AJAX. Si sabes cómo hacerlo con AJAX, seguro que al usuario le será útil.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo suelo hacer es que teniendo un formulario agrego un input de tipo hidden

```
<input type="hidden" id="variable" name="variable">
```

de esta forma en la parte de JavaScript creo una función en donde el valor de la variable lo agrego al input, de igual forma puedes crear el input en esta función y agregarle el valor

```
function extraer(){
    tuVariable = "X";
    var txt = document.getElementById("variable");
    txt.setAttribute("value",tuVariable);
}
```

Posteriormente en el formulario agrego el evento onclick donde hago referencia al método anterior, de esta forma el valor de la variable será enviada.

```
<form method="POST" action="/" >
    <input type="radio" name="tipo_cuenta" value="1" id="1-mes" checked="">
    <label for="1-mes">1 Mes</label>

    <input type="radio" name="tipo_cuenta" value="3" id="3-meses" checked="">
    <label for="3-meses">3 Meses</label>

    <input type="radio" name="tipo_cuenta" value="6" id="6-meses" checked="">
    <label for="6-meses">6 Meses</label>

    <input type="hidden" id="variable" name="variable">
    <button type="submit" onclick="extraer();">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Posteriormente en PHP recibes el valor del input

```
$variable = $_POST['variable'];
```

Espero te ayude, saludos

Comment: Ok me funcionó perfectamente pero lo que yo no quiero es que me vuelva a cargar la página pues el código que proporcione es para que cuando una persona seleccione el tipo de mes que quiera en este caso 1 Mes, 3 meses, y 12 meses y por ejemplo la persona le da en el radio 3 meses el monto de ejemplo el producto sale 3.50 cada mes y si la persona elige 3 meses el monto ya sería 10.5, no sé si me entendieron, gracias.

Comment: Entonces lo que buscas es cambiar el valor del producto al seleccionar la cantidad de meses, el valor del producto en que lo estas mostrando?, con que fin quieres pasar la variable de js a php?

Answer (score 0):

JavaSript se ejecuta en un cliente (en este caso) desde un navegador, php se ejecuta en un servidor, la forma de comunicarse entre ellos es (en general) mediante algun verbo http (GET, POST, PUT, etc), en donde el cliente (un navegador en este caso) realiza una petición de este tipo al servidor. Está bien dicho petición porque el servidor decide si le responde o no dependiendo de lo que se quiera.

En este caso que planteas, es necesario que esa petición transporte algún tipo de información, para que el servidor haga algo con ella.
Casi todas las formas que existen en las que el navegador haga una petición nos van a servir para llevar información al servidor.

Una forma habitual es haciendo ajax con JavaScript, mediante `fetch` o `XMLHttpRequest` la cual tiene la ventaja de ser asíncrona, la página no se recarga. Es decir con ajax lo que se hace es una petición http (GET, POST) al servidor.

Los formularios dentro de los tags `<form>` con un botón tipo `submit` también hacen una petición al servidor desde el HTML, esta forma es síncrona, la página se recarga, en ella indicamos también el verbo y la información que queremos enviar.

Los tags `<img>` o `<script>` entre otros, también hacen una petición (GET) al servidor desde HTML, en ellos la petición y/u otra información adicional está indicada en el atributo `src`.

Desde el lado del servidor, este tiene que ser capaz de esperar lo que que quieres enviar cuando el cliente hace una petición.

En el caso de php y las peticiones GET, la variable superglobal `$_GET` nos va a permitir acceder a las variables que se envíen por este medio, entonces si tenemos un archivo "codigo.php" en el que el contenido tenga:

`$_GET['mi_variable']`

cualquiera sea el medio que utilicemos para hacer una petición a "http://ejemplo.com?mi_variable=mi_valor" siempre vamos a obtener "mi_valor" en `$_GET['mi_variable']`.

una forma en javaScrtip, como ya dije, podría ser:

`fetch("http://ejemplo.com?mi_variable=mi_valor")`

en HTML

`<img src="http://ejemplo.com?mi_variable=mi_valor" />`

y un formulario HTML va a funcionar también.

Lo que determina que forma quieres utilizar esta dado principalmente por que quieres recibir como respuesta, si es que quieres recibir algo, o la posibilidad de controlar cuando se envía la petición exactamente.

Como lo que quieres enviar está accesible o se genera en un entorno de JavaScript pareciera que lo mejor sería utilizar `fetch` o `XMLHttpRequest`, si no necesitas una respuesta del servidor, con solo hacer `fetch("http://ejemplo.com?mi_variable=mi_valor")` será suficiente sino [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) tienes mas información.